# VB NET String Search

Tags: vb.net

How can I search for a string inside another one and then select all the characters till end of line ?
For example, given this string:

PrinterName: PDFCreator

PortName: PDFCreator:

Status: Unknown

DriverName: PDFCreator

PrinterName: Lexmark E360dn XL

PortName: someport

Status: Unknown

DriverName: Lexmark E360dn XL

HostAddress: somehostaddress

I'd like to search the string: "PrinterName" once it finds it, add it into a combobox, in order to get only the PrinterName.
So far i wrote this:

```
Dim TextSearched As String = tmp.Text
    Dim Paragraph As String = "PrinterName:"
    Dim location As Integer = 0
    Dim occurances As Integer = 0

    Do

        location = TextSearched.IndexOf(Paragraph, location)

        If location <> -1 Then

            occurances += 1
            If TextSearched.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then

                Debug.Print(TextSearched.Substring(location, TextSearched.IndexOf(vbCrLf)))

            End If
            location += Paragraph.Length

        End If



    Loop Until location = -1
```

where tmp.Text is a long string like the example above.

When i run it I get something like this:

PrinterName: PDFCreator

PrinterName: Lexmark E3

I don't get the "360dn XL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given any thought to using `Regex`?  You can use a pattern like:

```
"PrinterName: (.*?)\r\n"
```

Which should find the line in your long string and capture the data into group 1.  You would access the result like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim TextSearch As String = _
            "PrinterName : PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf + _
            "PortName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf + _
            "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf + _
            "DriverName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf + _
            "PrinterName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf + _
            "PortName: someport()" + vbCrLf + _
            "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf + _
            "DriverName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf + _
            "HostAddress: somehostaddress()"

        Dim Matcher = Regex.Match(TextSearch, "PrinterName: (.*?)\r\n")
        If Matcher.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(Matcher.Groups(1))
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
Lexmark E360dn XL
```

You would add `Matcher.Groups(1)` to your combobox.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I didn't know the existence of Regex; u opened my mind .
Tank you again sir.

Answer (score 1):

This involves some simple parsing using the IndexOf and SubString Extension Methods.  Here is an example that puts all of the PrinterName values into a List(of String).:

```
    Dim lstLines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Your\Location\tmp.txt").ToList()

    Dim lstPrinters As New List(Of String)

    lstLines.ForEach(Sub(strLine As String)
                         If strLine.IndexOf("PrinterName:") > -1 Then
                             lstPrinters.Add(strLine.Substring(strLine.IndexOf("PrinterName:") + 13))
                         End If
                     End Sub)
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer, but i'm giving the answer to Shar1er80 cause i didn't know the existence of Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Another one...

```
    Dim TextSearch As String =
        "PrinterName : PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "PortName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf +
        "DriverName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "PrinterName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf +
        "PortName: someport()" + vbCrLf +
        "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf +
        "DriverName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf +
        "HostAddress: somehostaddress()"

    Dim printers As List(Of String) = TextSearch.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(Function(x) x.ToLower.StartsWith("printername")).Select(Function(x) x.Split(":").Last).ToList
    For Each printer As String In printers
        Debug.Print(printer)
    Next
```

This could also be written as:

```
    Dim TextSearch As String =
        "PrinterName : PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "PortName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf +
        "DriverName: PDFCreator()" + vbCrLf +
        "PrinterName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf +
        "PortName: someport()" + vbCrLf +
        "Status: Unknown()" + vbCrLf +
        "DriverName: Lexmark E360dn XL" + vbCrLf +
        "HostAddress: somehostaddress()"

    Dim printers = From printer In TextSearch.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray)
                   Where printer.ToLower.StartsWith("printername")
                   Select printer.Split(":").Last
    For Each printer As String In printers
        Debug.Print(printer)
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer, but i'm giving the answer to Shar1er80 cause i didn't know the existence of Regex.

Comment: No problem.  I really like this [RegEx Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) site myself.